# In what order should I get the Gems needed for Mornstar?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I am at the point where I have learned the locations of the gems needed to complete Mornstar to return it to its former power. In the a previous scene I saw:

> where Shadar is given the power to control the Guardians who once obeyed the Wizard King

So, this gives me concern that each gem will be protected thus a boss fight.

I am wondering if there is a recommended order in terms of difficulty I should approach each of the gems? All 3 are pointed out by map markers on the world map, and I don't really want to go to one, find that I am under leveled for the boss and leave to tackle another gem while I get stronger

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a boss guarding each of the stones.

There is no special order in which you are required to fight them, but based both on my memory (played over a year ago) and the HP of each boss, which is a rough measurement of its power, this is the order I advice:

1. > Black Porpoise aka the Ghost Ship. (where you fight [Cap'n Crossbones](http://ninokuni.wikia.com/wiki/Cap'n_Crossbones))
2. > The Vault of Tears. (where you fight [Aapep](http://ninokuni.wikia.com/wiki/Aapep))
3. > The Glittering Grotto. (where you fight [Cerboreas](http://ninokuni.wikia.com/wiki/Cerboreas))